# Compile JasperReports jrxml with scriptlet dependency in same project via Maven

Tags: maven-2, jasper-reports

I have a report project that gets compiled, packaged, and included in a war. I use the jasperreports-maven-plugin to compile the JasperReports templates in the report project. I have an issue with a circular dependency where one of the templates requires a scriptlet class in the same project, but the scriptlet class does not get compiled before the reports and I get a ClassNotFound exception during compilation. Is there a way to compile the class first before the templates or some other workaround besides declaring a system dependency to a previously compiled version of the jar?

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>report</artifactId>

<name>report</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
                                <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>

                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-jasper</outputDirectory>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/com/example/report/</sourceDirectory>
                <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler</compiler>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- use this if you have a report dependency at compile time -->
                <!-- 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.example.usedforcompilingjasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compilejasperreports</artifactId>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <version>0.0.1</version>
                    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/com/example/report/lib/report-${version}.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
                -->
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jasperreports-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0-beta-2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- not used but necessary to avoid an unexpected compiletion exception 
            An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_04). Please file a bug at 
            the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport) after 
            checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following 
            diagnostic in your report. Thank you. com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: 
            class file for javax.persistence.CascadeType not found -->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sforce.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>salesforce-webservices</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>assemble</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../assemble/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
</project>
```

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a tad late, but I think you could try to bind the execution of the jasperreports-maven-plugin to a later maven build phase.

By default it runs at the generate-resources phase, at which time the java classes have not yet been compiled.

Check out the paragraph below the code box on [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/usage.html) page.

Comment: Brilliant! So simple too. Thank you sir.