# Importing custom classes in jrxml and compiling with maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, maven-plugin, jasper-plugin

I have to import few custom *Java* classes in *JasperReports*'s JRXML file.
I am able to do that using

```xml
<import value="org.ga.jasper.sample.MyCustomClass"/>
```

This works perfectly fine and I am able to run this jrxml and test my code.

Problem comes when I want to precompile this into .jasper file by using ***jasperreports-maven-plugin***.

When doing a build, it complains saying it does not find my package and hence import is invalid.

```
package org.ga.jasper.sample does not exist
import org.ga.jasper.sample.MyCustomClass;
```

FYI, My *Java* code and *.jrxml* are in the same maven module but in different folders.

Following is the code from my plugin tag

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile-reports</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/jasper</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
        <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue. Adding phase

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
             <execution>
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>  
                    <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                  </goals>
             </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
             <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/jasper</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
                <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
            </configuration>
          <dependencies>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
           </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What did you do can you explain what configurations fields you changed?

Answer (score 4):

By default, the plugin runs in the generate-resources phase, before the current module's classes have been compiled. You can change the plugin to run at the compile phase instead. See notes at bottom of page here:

- http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/usage.html

Also, see this similar q/a:

- [Compile JasperReports jrxml with scriptlet dependency in same project via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840791/compile-jasperreports-jrxml-with-scriptlet-dependency-in-same-project-via-maven)